# How read a data file which has both hour format and numeric data in gnu octave?

Tags: octave

I'm needing to read a file in octave, that in every line it has time format (data and hour) values and some temperature measurements, each one separated by semicolon. For example, supposing that my file, filename.txt, has the following datas:

```
08/07/2018;09:50:51;0.0;0.0;19.6
08/07/2018;09:50:58;0.0;0.0;19.5
08/07/2018;09:51:12;0.0;0.0;19.5
```

My purpose for this is to convert the hours in relative seconds with respect  some reference time. I already tried with dlmread command in order to specify the values separator, by writting

```
M = dlmread('filename.txt',";")
```

but octaves actually reads:

```
M = 
8 9 0 0 19.6
8 9 0 0 19.5
8 9 0 0 19.5
```

What is the way for say to octave read completely  the whole datas in the file?

Thanks for any gived help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dlmread` is going to try to coerce everything to be a number so that it can return the result in a matrix. Rather than using `dlmread`, you will probably want to use `textscan` instead, read the first two columns in as strings and the remaining columns as floats:

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt', 'rb');
data = textscan(fid, '%s %s %f %f %f', 'Delimiter', ';');
```

Then you can combine the first and second columns into a date string and compute their `datenum` allowing you to put everything into a numeric matrix where the first column is the timestamp:

```
dates = cellfun(@(day, time)datenum([day, ' ', time], 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS'), data{1:2})
data = [dates(:), data{3:end}]

%   737279.41031        0.00000        0.00000       19.60000
%   737279.41039        0.00000        0.00000       19.50000
%   737279.41056        0.00000        0.00000       19.50000
```

You can then use these timestamps to determine the difference (in time) relative to whatever reference you wan using simple subtraction.